# Relaciones del Modelo en Angular 5

Tags: angular5, http, djangorestframework, relaciones

¿Alguna idea de cómo trabajar las relaciones de mi backend en Angularn5 (frontend)?

Tengo DjangoRest como backend y estoy usando Angular5 como frontend, y obtengo los datos por medio de http en formato json, pero el problema lo tengo al tratar las relaciones del backend, ya que los json los listas de cada tabla y a través de codigo que yo hago tengo que preseantar los datos.

Esta es una muestra sencilla de mi problema:
[image: Modelo Backend DjangoRest]

Y para presentar en la vista tengo que comparar las 3 listas obtenidas de las 3 tablas.

¿Hay código que Angular autogenere para esto?¿Hays alguna forma más eficiente?

Esto uso en mi service.ts

```
getActividades(): Promise<Actividad[]> {
  return this.http.get( 'http://localhost:8000/actividad?format=json{headers: this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json() as Actividad[])
}
```

y me retorna el json:

```
[{"id":2,"nombre":"¿Qué es la Dirección de Proyectos?","objetivo":"","descripcion":"Ver video de lo que es la dirección de proyectos.\r\n\r\nLink del video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlyrriEzx3o","entrega":"","fecha":"2018-10-24","aprobado":false,"en_revision":true,"hecho":false,"documento_adjunto":"","metodologia":{"id":2,"nombre":"Tradicional","descripcion":"sin definir","timestamp":"2018-10-08T18:16:58.020307Z","lastModification":"2018-10-08T18:16:58.020307Z"},"competenciaspropuestas":["Éxito en la Dirección de Proyectos: 1","Cambios: 2"],"resultadosaprendizajespropuestos":["Formular y evaluar proyectos de tecnologías de información: Básico"],"timestamp":"2018-10-08T18:56:43.729047Z","lastModification":"2018-10-25T18:25:57.419596Z"},{"id":3,"nombre":"EDT","objetivo":"Comprender y aplicar la herramienta EDT en un proyecto simple","descripcion":"Realizar EDT del desarrollo de una app móvil para hacer compras de artículos gamer PC","entrega":"En papel, durante la clase - 20 minutos para desarrollarlo","fecha":"2018-12-28","aprobado":true,"en_revision":false,"hecho":false,"documento_adjunto":"","metodologia":{"id":2,"nombre":"Tradicional","descripcion":"sin definir","timestamp":"2018-10-08T18:16:58.020307Z","lastModification":"2018-10-08T18:16:58.020307Z"},"competenciaspropuestas":["Estructuras de proyectos: 4","Alcance y entregables: 4","Tiempo y fases de los proyectos: 4"],"resultadosaprendizajespropuestos":["Administrar y gestionar proyectos informáticos: Avanzado"],"timestamp":"2018-10-23T15:10:47.497599Z","lastModification":"2018-10-23T15:10:47.497599Z"}]
```

Y así con las 3 tablas ... luego comparo los ID del json de la "Actividad" y el de la "CompetenciaPropuesta" para luego compararlo con el json de la "Competencia" y obtener el nombre de la "Competencia" que corresponde a la "Actividad" ....

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Podrías compartir el json, lo que quieres es hacer join de los registros en angular ?, encontré una pregunta parecida a lo que quieres lograr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993468/angular-4-combine-data-from-multiple-http-requests

Comment: lo agregué ...si, quiero hacer un join ... revisaré rxjs de Typescript, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si quiere generar un relación en representación de modelos seria algo así. No entiendo la comparativa en el front ?

```
export class Metodologia {
  id?: number;
  nombre: string;
  descripcion: string;
  timestamp: string;
  lastModification: string;
}

export class CompetenciaCompuesta {
  id? : number;
  nombre: string;
  objetivo: string;
  descripcion: string;
  fecha: string;
  aprovado: boolean;
  en_revision: boolean;
  hecho: boolean;
  documento_adjunto: string;
  metodologia: Metodologia;
  competenciaspropuestas: string[];
  resultadosaprendizajespropuestos: string[];
}
```

Comment: entonces podría "anidar" 2 modelos en uno?

Comment: Esto seria la representación desde front para que no marque ningún error diciendo que la propiedad no existe, si quisiera unir un json con dos modelos eso seria trabajo adecuado para el back-end no para el front. En rails mostrar este tipo de relaciones es muy simple mediante serializer

Comment: DjangoRest también usa "serializers", debería representar las relaciones en los serializers? ... si es así, la representación de modelos en el front sería la misma que propones?

Comment: modifiqué el json que retorna (utilizé serializers.StringRelatedField en el back "DjangoRest"), puedes modificar tu respuesta de como quedaría el model para ese json? específicamente me interesa representar "competenciaspropuestas" y "resultadosaprendizajespropuestos". Gracias!